# Reversing setClickable(false) effect

Tags: android

I've a expandable listview in my project and each group has an edittext as its child. I'm changing the edittext as non clickable based on some data. But I'm not able to reverse it since I'm using the same layout for all child.

Snippet:

```
if(**condition**)
{
    edittext.setFocusable(true);
}
else
{
    edittext.setFocusable(false);
}
```

Once it enters the `else` part, Its not working for the `if` part

Comment: you will need to get the position of the corresponding child, otherwise it's not gonna work. Then you can use setItemChecked(position, value) for example. And disable or enable checked items.

Comment: @Mojo, try to use addTextwatcher for your EditText it have methods to go with beforeTextChange/OnTextchange/afterTextChanged methods. Use along with Regular expression to stop/continue entering data..please check below link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html